# Missing separator on line 1 of makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

Makefile appears below
Separator error is noted for line 1 of the makefile
"
make clean
Makefile:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
"
        /******************************************************************************/
        /* Blah Blah Blah                   */
        /*                                      */
        /*FOOBAR            */
        /*FOOBAR            */
        /*FOOBAR            */
        /*FOOBAR        */
        /*FOOBAR                    */
        /*                                      */
        /*FOOBAR        */
        /*FOOBAR                                */

```
    /*                                      */
    /*  FOOBAR              */
    /*  FOOBAR                      */  
    /*  FOOBAR                              */
    /*  FOOBAR                          */
    /*                                      */
    /*                                      */
    /* FOOBAR           */
    /* FOOBAR       */
    /* FOOBAR                       */

/*                                      */
/* FOOBAR                   */
/* FOOBAR               */
/* FOOBAR               */
/*                                      */
/* FOOBAR                                   */
/* FOOBAR       */
/* FOOBAR       */
/* FOOBAR           */
/* FOOBAR       */
/* FOOBAR       */
/* FOOBAR       */
/* FOOBAR   */
/* FOOBAR   */
/* FOOBAR   */
/* FOOBAR*/
/*                                      */
/* Makefile                                 */
/*******************************************************************************/

CC  = gcc
CXX = g++
CFLAGS  = -c -Wall -g   -W -I../include/ -I../msgInclude/ -I../nsiInclude/ -I../mfaInclude/ -I../fpgaInclude/ 
CXXFLAGS    = -c -Wall -g   -DMULTICAST_EQ36 -W -I../include/ -I../msgInclude/ -I../nsiInclude/ -I../mfaInclude/ -I../fpgaInclude/ -Wno-deprecated
LDFLAGS =  -lrt -lnsl -lpthread

OBJDIR  = ../obj
EXEDIR  = ../p_bin
CDIR    = ../c_code

PROG    = fast_msg_broker_rtc
EXECUTABLE  = $(EXEDIR)/$(PROG)

CXXSOURCES  = message_broker.cpp \
    a1.cpp \
    a2.cpp \
    a3.cpp \
    a4.cpp 


CSOURCES    = $(CDIR)/tcc_rta.c
#CSOURCES   = $(CDIR)/tcc_rti.c

CXXOBJECTS  = $(CXXSOURCES:.cpp=.opp)
COBJECTS    = $(CSOURCES:.c=.o)
OBJECTS = $(CXXOBJECTS) $(COBJECTS)
#OBJECTS    = $(COBJECTS)
OBJFILES    = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(OBJECTS))

all:  $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJFILES)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/%.opp: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
    echo $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    -rm -rf $(OBJFILES)
    -rm -f $(EXECUTABLE)
    clear
```

Comment: Try with '#' instead of '/*...*/'

Comment: That's not a valid makefile, what gave you the idea that you could use `/* ... */` comments in a makefile? And when it gave an error on line one, why didn't you try removing the comments?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use C style comments `/* like these */` in a Makefile.

Makefile comments, like many other comments in scripted languages, are formed with a `#` at the beginning of the line:

```
# FOOBAR
# FOOBAR, FOOBAR. #
```